# How to equate and/or compare four different variables that hold strings in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have four different variables, say,

```
s1 = 'Foo'
s2 = 'Boo'
s3 = 'Foo'
s4 = 'Duh'
```

Now, I would like to form a string of every unique value from all of `s1`, `s2`, `s3` and `s4` **keeping the order**. Like in the above case the string would be something like:

```
"We have a collection of types 'Foo', 'Boo' and 'Duh'."
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Something like: `set([s1,s2,s3,s4])` ?

Comment: If sequence doesn't matter, Mamka's solution should work well.

Comment: @YiFei How can we modify Mamka's solution if sequence does matter?

Comment: Set itself won't preserve any order, so you have to use a list. Wiktor has already posted an answer. If you have really a large number of variable, you can utilize python's *built-in* reflective programming and maintain both a list and set to ensure the performance, if needed. And if you want to preserve the order, you should specify it in your post, then it won't be marked as duplicate. Maybe it's still duplicate, I'm not sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of duplicates *and* preserve the order of occurrence, you need to append values "manually":

```
s = "We have a collection of types {}."
lst = [s1,s2,s3,s4]
fin = []
for x in lst:
    if x not in fin:
        fin.append(x)
print(s.format(", ".join(fin)))
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/5SyRDz)

**If you were not going to preserve the order**, you might use `set` that would return unique items in a list (just create a list from your variables):

```
s1 = 'Foo'
s2 = 'Boo'
s3 = 'Foo'
s4 = 'Duh'
print("We have a collection of types {}.".format(", ".join(set([s1,s2,s3,s4]))))
```

where:

- `"We have a collection of types {}.".format()` is the string format method where the string literal contains a `{}` that is a placeholder for the only argument passed to the `format` method
- `", ".join()` - a method to make a string out of a list joining the items with a comma+space
- `set()` - a method that takes an iterable and returns a frozenset, unique items in the iterable
- `[s1,s2,s3,s4]` - a list created from the standalone vars

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7FZ0Bh)

Comment: This did the trick. If you don't mind, can you explain what `format`, `join` does in `print("We have a collection of types {}.".format(", ".join(list(set([s1,s2,s3,s4])))))`?

Comment: I updated the answer with explanations. I have double checked, and actually, you can even do without a `list()` as `join` will join the items in the set() result.

Comment: Great. How can I modify the above to put them in sequence s1,s2,s3,s4. That is, in the way that others should follow s1's value always.

Comment: Do you mean that `Duh, Foo, Boo` is not what you want, and you want `Foo, Boo, Duh`?

Comment: That's right. I want to make sure that `Foo` (or whatever is `s1`'s value) comes first.

Comment: I added this solution, too.